# Switch between my app and other app with single tap

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to switch between my app and other app with single taping.
Is it possible?

**Briefly:**

Consider one activity(My App) with one button,when i tap on that button it should open the first recent activity(Other app) then my app should create another button over the Recent activity(Other app) after doing some operation on other activity,when i tap on button it should return to my activity.Is it possible?

**Updated:**

Is it possible by using Floating icon?
and is good to use floating icon?

Comment: I don't want to open particular application.It should open the first recently opened app.

Comment: Create a button on another app? I think it's possible with some "magic" tricks, like create a button that seems inserted in the destination app but it's drawn over it.

Comment: OK.I want to create over it but at some corner of the screen and able to move over it.

Comment: You dont have any control over other app. Simply it's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can or should be done. I don't think there's a way to impose a button or widget from your app on top of another app.

What you *can* do, is to have a button on your app that causes it to finish (thus causing the most recent previous app to return to the top) **and** create a notification in the notification bar that brings your app back. This gives the user a way to instantly return to your app at any time.

Answer (score 0):

No You can put your button on other App or Other Activity. You should make use of startActivityForResult() to start other App and override the method activityForResult in your Activity. When you came back from other app to your app , you will get result as Bundle.

Refer Doc : 
Starting Activities and Getting Results

The startActivity(Intent) method is used to start a new activity, which will be placed at the top of the activity stack. It takes a single argument, an Intent, which describes the activity to be executed.

Sometimes you want to get a result back from an activity when it ends. For example, you may start an activity that lets the user pick a person in a list of contacts; when it ends, it returns the person that was selected. To do this, you call the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) version with a second integer parameter identifying the call. The result will come back through your onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) method.

When an activity exits, it can call setResult(int) to return data back to its parent. It must always supply a result code, which can be the standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER. In addition, it can optionally return back an Intent containing any additional data it wants. All of this information appears back on the parent's Activity.onActivityResult(), along with the integer identifier it originally supplied.

If a child activity fails for any reason (such as crashing), the parent activity will receive a result with the code RESULT_CANCELED.